# Cordova/Phonegap Application Manifest

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, android-manifest

We've all seen the nicely laid-out description pages that most Android apps have nowadays. Developers can include images, videos, formatted feature lists, and "what's new" bulletins to advertise new functionality and drive users to update to the latest version. I'm building a Cordova/Phonegap app, and I want to take advantage of these features. However, I don't see any mention in the appropriate docs of how to do this beyond a simple string description and an application icon. Is this even possible?

My initial guess is that there's some way to declare a custom XML structure in the Cordova config file, but I'm not sure what that structure would look like. Another possibility that has crossed my mind is that there may be a way to embed HTML into the description tag. I just can't seem to find any concrete info on the web.

Here's a sample image to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve (image taken from the Guardian app in the Google Play Store).

[image: a busy cat](http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg)![The Guardian description page in Google Play]

Comment: This is done in the app store dev areas when you prep for release.  Check out https://play.google.com/apps/publish/ for googles console.

Comment: Thank you so much! Would you mind posting this comment as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

This is done in the app store dev areas when you prep for release.

In terms of the app stores display, the config.xml file is used for versioning, setting up a launcher icon, setting an author, and naming the package.

Setting the descriptions, changelog, and other pieces of the app's display in the stores is done when you set up your release.

Poking around the app store dev consoles is a great place to start: https://play.google.com/apps/publish/,https://appworld.blackberry.com/isvportal/home.do and https://itunesconnect.apple.com/ for Google, BlackBerry and Apple.